# Expression always equals 0

Tags: php, wordpress, function, expression, shortcode

The output of the function profile_lvl() is 3, whereas the output of the function profile_percentage() is 0. I've tried using a integer conversion but that did not work. I'm completely stumped on this.

```
function profile_lvl() {
$profilelvl = do_shortcode( '[mycred_my_rank user_id = "'.bp_displayed_user_id().'"]' );
return $profilelvl;
}
function profile_percentage() {
$profilelvl = profile_lvl();
$profilepercentage = $profilelvl*99;
return $profilepercentage;
}
```

Comment: what is `do_shortcode()` about?

Comment: so if you input 3 you should output 297 according to your second function.

Comment: @shnisaka is right, I've already check it

Comment: please give the output of do_shortcode

Comment: yeah the output is supposed to be 297. do_shortcode() retrieves the users level in which case my test returns 3.

Comment: @BenHayward What is the output of: `var_dump(profile_lvl());` ?

Comment: @BenHayward Then try this `$profilelvl = trim(profile_lvl());` does that works for you?

Comment: nope it is still returning 0

Comment: Does it works if you change the function call with 3 ? like: `$profilelvl = 3;`

Comment: @Rizier123 yeah this is why im so confused.

Comment: @BenHayward If you do `var_dump(profile_lvl());` do: view source code and please post like a pastebin with the exact output

Comment: string(35) "<div class="mycred-my-rank">3</div>"

Comment: @Rizier123 oh I kinda see what is happening how will i sort this?

Comment: @BenHayward i though that this happened, try this: `$profilelvl = filter_var(profile_lvl(), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);` It's a hard error to spot it!

Comment: @BenHayward Try this: `return strip_tags($profilelvl);`

Comment: @Rizier123 thank you!! that worked! i would have never spotted that error!

Answer (score 1):

I think you got html tags in your variable so, you can extract the number with:

```
$profilelvl = filter_var(profile_lvl(), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```